# want to write background location tracking application android

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

Hi Everyone I want to create location tracking application in android which runs in background even after user terminates application by left swipe from recent application. till now i have used intent service started from main activity but it gets killed when i terminate application.
Any other idea to implement this?
I have tried by registering location updates and doing work of service in onLocation changed event. but listener also gets unregister after application exists.
I don't need full code but i need approach to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to track in a `Service`? Without reference to the activity. You have the start the service from the activity for the first time.
Note: A service isn't killed by swiping from recent apps, rather it is killed by the OS when more ram is required. To restart it after its killed you have to return `START_STICKY` to `onStartCommand` i.e:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Also, here you should register your `LocationListener` and perform whatever action you need.
And as always, remember to add permissions.

Comment: I tried with IntentService. yes i put Start_stickey. let me try with Service.